# Use Extension to filter OneToMany relationship

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, doctrine-extensions

I'm using API Platform 3 and Gedmo's Softdeleteable Extension. For my entities, I'm using Extensions to add `$queryBuilder->andWhere('o.deletedAt IS NULL')` to all queries.

This is working fine, but when using OneToMany relations, API Platform doesn't use these extensions and therefor shows 'softdeleted' entities.

Let's take a slightly modified [example from their documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#example):

```
#[ApiResource]
class User
{
    #[ORM\OneToMany] 
    #[Serializer\Groups(['user'])]
    public Collection $offers;
}
```

`/api/offers/1` correctly shows a 404, because it has been softdeleted. But `/api/users/1` shows something like this:

```
{
    username: 'foo',
    offers:
    {
        '@id': "/api/offers/1",
        deletedAt: "2022-01-27T12:04:45+01:00"
    }
}
```

How can I change the query that API Platform uses to fetch the relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two methods of achieving this.

1. Filter hydrated objects:

Inside the existing (or completely new) getter:

```
return $this->offers->filter(function(Offer offer){
   return $offer->getDeletedAt() !== NULL;
});
```

2. Apply criteria to query:

Again, inside the existing (or completely new) getter:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('deletedAt', NULL));

return $this->offers->matching($criteria);
```

The `Criteria` method is preferable if your user could have LOTS of deleted offers - the filtering would be performed on a database level.

Hope this helps.

Btw, both of these methods are well explained in SymfonyCasts tutorials:

- https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/filtered-collection
- https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-doctrine-relations/collection-criteria